# dotnet webapp not running on localhost:5000 / 50001

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to run a dotnet webapp project in visual studio. When I run pops up a powershell window and it's saying that my application is running on https://localhost:5000 or localhost:5001. But when I try to access it appears: this localhost page can't be found. [browser screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcKwm.png)

[powershell screen-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYytD.png)

Comment: It might be a bit of an assumption that it's not running on localhost:5001, it possibly is - but it just can't find that route (`/`). Do you definitely have an endpoint that can serve that route?

Comment: You can verify @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ claim by changing the logging level in the appsettings.Development.json file for "Microsoft.AspNetCore" and "Default" to Debug.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Is the non-secure version reachable? (`http://localhost:5000`).

Answer (score 1):

As [Charles Mager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320845/charles-mager) commented above

> dotnet dev-certs https --trust

this answer worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like you.

Probably you have the problems with certificate.

So try to run this PowerShell script for that ports :

```
Start-Transcript -Path "$($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).log"
try {
    Write-Host "Creating cert resources"
    $ekuOidCollection = [System.Security.Cryptography.OidCollection]::new();
    $ekuOidCollection.Add([System.Security.Cryptography.Oid]::new("1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1","Server Authentication")) | Out-Null
    $sanBuilder = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.SubjectAlternativeNameBuilder]::new();
    $sanBuilder.AddDnsName("localhost") | Out-Null

Write-Host "Creating cert extensions"
$certificateExtensions = @(
    # Subject Alternative Name
    $sanBuilder.Build($true),        
    # ASP.NET Core OID
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Extension]::new(
        "1.3.6.1.4.1.311.84.1.1",
        [System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes("IIS Express Development Certificate"),
        $false),
        # KeyUsage
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageExtension]::new(
            [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyUsageFlags]::KeyEncipherment,
            $true),
            # Enhanced key usage
    [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension]::new(
        $ekuOidCollection,
        $true),
        # Basic constraints
        [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509BasicConstraintsExtension]::new($false,$false,0,$true)
    )
Write-Host "Creating cert parameters"
$parameters = @{
    Subject = "localhost";
    KeyAlgorithm = "RSA";
    KeyLength = 2048;
    CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\LocalMachine\My";
    KeyExportPolicy = "Exportable";
    NotBefore = Get-Date;
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(1);
    HashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
    Extension = $certificateExtensions;
    SuppressOid = @("2.5.29.14");
    FriendlyName = "IIS Express Development Certificate"
}
Write-Host "Creating cert"
$cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @parameters

$rootStore = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Store -ArgumentList Root, LocalMachine
$rootStore.Open("MaxAllowed")
$rootStore.Add($cert)
$rootStore.Close()

Write-Host "Creating port bindings"
# Add an Http.Sys binding for port 44300-44399
$command = 'netsh'
for ($i=5000; $i -le 5002; $i++) {
    $optionsDelete = @('http', 'delete', 'sslcert', "ipport=0.0.0.0:$i")
    $optionsAdd = @('http', 'add', 'sslcert', "ipport=0.0.0.0:$i", "certhash=$($cert.Thumbprint)", 'appid={214124cd-d05b-4309-9af9-9caa44b2b74a}')
    Write-Host "Running $command $optionsDelete"
    & $command $optionsDelete
    Write-Host "Running $command $optionsAdd"
    & $command $optionsAdd
} 
}
catch {
    Write-Error $_.Exception.Message
}
finally {
    Stop-Transcript
}
```

I hope that will work for you too!

Comment: I'm not clear what this does, but I'm not sure it's relevant unless IIS Express happens to be used. Any dev-time certificate issues are usually logged to the console and can be fixed with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`.

Comment: Be careful while running power shell :)